# Scraping specific td from table python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have this piece of code i want to scrape from a table:

```
<tr id="vsViewer1_dgMainView_dgMainView_ctl02" class="GridItem odd">
<td class=" ">
    <a class="hlPopup" id="lbdgMainView$ctl02" name="lbdgMainView$ctl02" onclick="wrjl_test(this,&#39;lbdgMainView$ctl02&#39;,&#39;746402:O9oY58XKE+w=:746402:746402&#39;)" onmouseover="this.className=&#39;HLPopupOver&#39;" onmouseout="this.className=&#39;HLPopup&#39;"></a>
    <span class="HLPopup" id="lbldgMainView$ctl02" name="lbldgMainView$ctl02" onclick="wrjl_test(this,&#39;lbldgMainView$ctl02&#39;,&#39;746402:O9oY58XKE+w=:746402:746402&#39;)"> Info </span>
</td>
<td align="center" class=" ">746402</td>
<td align="center" class=" ">Wyndham Orlando Resort International Drive</td>
<td align="center" class=" ">Interiano, Ana</td>
<td align="center" class=" ">Yes</td>
<td align="center" class=" ">7.32</td>
<td align="left" class=" ">
    <table width="250" class="TextTableSmall" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-align: center; font-size: 8pt;">Date</td>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-align: center; font-size: 8pt;">In</td>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-align: center; font-size: 8pt;">Out</td>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-align: center; font-size: 8pt;">Hours</td>
                <td style="background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128); text-align: center; font-size: 8pt;">Shift</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;">Thu 10/24/19</td>
                <td align="right" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;">8:00am</td>
                <td align="right" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;">1:20pm</td>
                <td align="right" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;">5.33</td>
                <td align="center" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;">1
                    <br>FL ORL Wyndham Resort I Drive 18128 - Housekeeping
                        <br>Room Attendant
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;">Thu 10/24/19</td>
                        <td align="right" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;">1:39pm</td>
                        <td align="right" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;">3:38pm</td>
                        <td align="right" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;">1.98</td>
                        <td align="center" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 153); text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;">1
                            <br>FL ORL Wyndham Resort I Drive 18128 - Housekeeping
                                <br>Room Attendant
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td align="right" class=" ">12.25</td>
                <td class=" ">9.0000</td>
                <td align="center" class=" ">1</td>
                <td align="center" class=" ">Housekeeper</td>
                <td align="center" class=" ">HOUSEKEEPER</td>
                <td align="center" class=" ">SE-FL-Orlando</td>
                <td align="center" class=" ">Wyndham Hotel Group</td>
            </tr>
```

i've done this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

with open('vsShowViewTWO.html') as html_file:
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file,'lxml')

tbody = soup.find('tbody',id='thetbody')

table_rows=tbody.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

and the results are:

[' Info ', '746402', 'Resort International', 'Interiano, Ana', 'Yes', '7.32', 'DateInOutHoursShiftThu 10/24/198:00am1:20pm5.331Resort I Drive 18128 - HousekeepingRoom AttendantThu 10/24/191:39pm3:38pm1.981Resort I Drive 18128 - HousekeepingRoom Attendant', 'Date', 'In', 'Out', 'Hours', 'Shift', 'Thu 10/24/19', '8:00am', '1:20pm', '5.33', '1Resort I Drive 18128 - HousekeepingRoom Attendant', 'Thu 10/24/19', '1:39pm', '3:38pm', '1.98', '1 Resort I Drive 18128 - HousekeepingRoom Attendant', '12.25', '9.0000', '1', 'Housekeeper', 'HOUSEKEEPER', 'SE', 'Hotel Group']

but i don't need the whole row just the name "Interiano, Ana" and the last "HOUSEKEEPER", i've been trying with indexing the rows var with no luck

Comment: You should think of a way to identify or differentiate the the name from the rest. Looking at your table data, there is no way to know the name unless you are sure that the name is on the fourth column of your table. In that case you can put name = row[3]

Comment: you have missed part of the html. The but with housekeeper is missing. Can you include the full table?

Comment: You´re right, the html code was missing a part

Comment: Is the top html exactly as comes from response and not malformed? I'd look at td:nth-of-type and next_sibling.